ALT + TAB (release TAB) + Q override or remove this keybind from Gnome
Related to:
When holding Alt + Tab, how to prevent the Q key from closing applications?
This incredibly annoying because it's really easy to close a random window and misclick a button
It deletes a focused window instantly when still in ALT-TAB view
